# How to set size and position of a MDI Client?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, visual-c++-2015

It seems like both size (`x`, `y`) and position (`nWidth`, `nHeight`) arguments are ignored when using [`CreateWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For example:

```
CreateWindow(L"MDICLIENT", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_VISIBLE,
             150, 10, 400, 300, hWnd, NULL, hInst, (LPVOID)&ccs);
```

It's always aligned to the top-left corner and takes the parent's size, as shown below.

[image]

(We could see the difference since the window background is `COLOR_WINDOW`).

Comment: That is correct. `MDICLIENT` fits the entire client area. x/y/w/h coordinates are ignored. You can set the initial coordinates of MDI-child if you want, and you can restrict the movement of MDI-child, that should probably achieve whatever you were trying to do by changing MDI client position.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Actually I want to add other controls as well to the parent window, but not inside the MDI client.

Comment: MDI client has `COLOR_APPWORKSPACE` color not `COLOR_WINDOW`

Comment: Add other controls then. The client will fill what's left.

Comment: @milevyo Was talking about the background window.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If I add other controls they'll be "inside" (at the top of) the MDI client...

Comment: That's not my recollection. Perhaps I'm remembering wrongly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coordinates for `MDICLIENT` have no effect on start up. Instead you have to handle client-size in `WM_SIZE` as follows:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK FrameWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HWND hwndClient;
    switch (message)
    {

    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        hwndClient = CreateWindow(L"MDICLIENT", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_VISIBLE,
            0, 0, 0, 0, hWnd, NULL, hInst, (LPVOID)&ccs);
        ...
        return 0;
    }

    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        RECT rc;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);

        SetWindowPos(hwndToolbar, 0, 0, 0, rc.right, 30, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);

        int x = 50; //right-edge of another toolbar...
        int y = 30;
        int w = rc.right - x;
        int h = rc.bottom - y;
        MoveWindow(hwndClient, x, y, w, h, 0);
        return 0;
    }
    ...
}
```

By the way, you won't really see any difference on the screen unless you add MDI child. The MDI child will limit its movements to the new area, it won't go over the toolbar.